# Change table schema in the workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have three different `schemas`, ended up creating all the `tables` in one, but now I want to put them in their correct `schemas`.

[image: enter image description here]]

How can I do this without using scripts?
the version of `Workbench` that use is `6.3.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "MySQL Model" page you can cut and paste your objects between schemas:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it worked, newbie question